# Automatically convert formats of of date-time data to date only in r

Tags: r, datetime, parsing

I have a dataframe that has been put together by binding the data together after reading in multiple .csv files. The data comprises 6 variables and approx. 560,000 observations.

One variable 'date.time' unfortunately is currently in two formats `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss` and `dd/mm/yy hh:mm`. What I would like to do is `mutate()` the variable to a date only format.

I have tried  `df %>% mutate(date = as.Date(dmy_hms(date.time))` but I get an error failed to parse as you would expect given I have two date/time formats in the same column.

Another way I have tried is `df %>% mutate(date = anydate(date.time))` using `anydate()` from the anytime package, but this is far too slow and the CPU environment I'm working in uses all available memory given the size of the dataframe.

I'm hoping there is a swift and easy way of addressing this.

Thanks.

Comment: Some sample data could help providing an answer that works on your production data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

````r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

``` r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  mutate(time_temp = dmy_hms(time, quiet = TRUE)) %>% 
  mutate(time = if_else(is.na(time_temp), 
                        dmy_hm(time, quiet = TRUE),
                        time_temp)) %>% 
  select(-time_temp)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 1
#>   time               
#>   <dttm>             
#> 1 2020-01-01 00:00:01
#> 2 2020-01-02 00:01:01
#> 3 2020-01-04 00:02:00
#> 4 2020-01-03 01:02:00
````

## reprex data

```
df <- tibble(
  time = c("01/01/2020 00:00:01", "02/01/2020 00:01:01", "04/01/20 00:02", "03/01/20 01:02")
)
```